# Chulada Shop or The Chulada Shop? Which one is correct?

Tags: grammar

What is grammatically correct for a business name, **Chulada Shop** or ***The* Chulada Shop**? Why? My online business (I sell Mexican accessories) is called Chulada Shop but I wonder if it's grammatically correct, my native language is Spanish. Please help :)

Comment: Names are not meant to be complete sentences. Some names have "the" as part of the name, some don't  "The UK", but "Britain".

Answer (score 0):

They are both correct. It is a mater of choice whether to use the article or not.

Using the definite article, will make the name of the shop more "grammatically correct". Of course, since there is no sentence, there is no really grammar, but it will sound better. And it will make the name longer.

If you do not use the article, then it still sounds OK (not as well as previously), but the name is shorter.